# Building Android AOSP fails after adding new API as there are new APIs than the previous SDK release. How to fix this?

Tags: android, api

I am adding a new API in Android input layer. I am getting an error while building aosp due to new API available than the previous SDK release. How to fix this?

I have copied the error below:

---

Checking API: checkpublicapi-last
java -Xmx1024m -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin//javac:out/host/linux-x86/framework/doclava.jar:out/host/linux-x86/framework/jsilver.jar com.google.doclava.apicheck.ApiCheck -hide 2 -hide 3 -hide 4 -hide 5 -hide 6 -hide 24 -hide 25 -hide 26 -hide 27 -error 7 -error 8 -error 9 -error 10 -error 11 -error 12 -error 13 -error 14 -error 15 -error 16 -error 17 -error 18 prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt frameworks/base/api/removed.txt out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/removed.txt

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javadoc/ClassDoc
        at com.google.doclava.apicheck.ApiFile.parsePackage(ApiFile.java:97)
        at com.google.doclava.apicheck.ApiFile.parseApi(ApiFile.java:76)
        at com.google.doclava.apicheck.ApiCheck.parseApi(ApiCheck.java:144)
        at com.google.doclava.apicheck.ApiCheck.checkApi(ApiCheck.java:112)
        at com.google.doclava.apicheck.ApiCheck.main(ApiCheck.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javadoc.ClassDoc
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 5 more
```

---

You have tried to change the API from what has been previously released in
an SDK.  Please fix the errors listed above.

---

make: *** [out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checkpublicapi-last-timestamp] Error 38

---

Answer (score 1):

If you are not rebuilding the entire AOSP by doing a `make clean` and `make -j8`, then this error may crop up. Try doing a clean build of AOSP as building without cleaning will not rebuild any previously built objects and intermediates, which do not have to built again after your modifications.

Comment: I am able to build the code with 'mm'. When I run 'mmm' in the frameworks folder I get this error due to the API change. Do you think still make clean and make will help?

Comment: When you do a mm or a mmm, it only builds the specific module you are targeting. You can try removing the intermediates from `out/target/product/<productname>/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/` and and then doing a `mmm frameworks` to see if the error still persists, before doing a clean build of the entire AOSP.

Answer (score -1):

Switching from OpenJDK to Oracle Java solved the issue.